# Hashset size operation

Tags: java, hashset

How is the size operation of a HashSet constant time operation?
I read that the contains and size operation is constant time.
Although I understand how contains is a constant-time operation, wouldn't size operation be proportionate (not linear) with number of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer - it's cached.

The longer answer:
`HashSet` is a `Set` implementation that holds a `HashMap`, where all the values are the same "dummy value". It's `size()` method just returns the map's `size()`. If you look into `HashMap`'s implementation, you'll see it has a `size` member. Adding elements to the map (e.g., by using `put` or `putAll`) increase the `size` and removing elements from it reduce the `size`. This way, as `size` is always kept up to date, it can simply be returned when `size()` is called, guaranteeing a constant time execution.

Answer (score 2):

HashSet internally stores how many elements it has.

> wouldnt size operation be proportionate(not linear) with number of elements?

If this weren't stored in a field for record keeping, size() would be proportionate to the size of the *backing* hash table, not the number of elements, since you'd have to scan over all entries to see if something's there. These tend to be the ~same (within 2x), except for when the hash table was either allocated to be significantly too big or a lot of elements were deleted.